# VB.Net JavaScriptSerializer Only getting first value of JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, windows, serialization

I am currently attempting to Convert some json

```
{"payload":{"versions":[{"1.0.2":{"vnum":"1.0.2","vloc":"http:\/\/*domainomitted*\/flyswatter\/files\/flyswatter_102.zip"},"1.0.1":{"vnum":"1.0.1","vloc":"http:\/\/*domainomitted*\/flyswatter\/files\/flyswatter_101.zip"}}]}}
```

Into a Iteratorable Object in VB.Net Here is what I have at the moment but it only returns the first element from the json array:

```
Dim vNum() As Object = j.getCfg("versions", False)
'Data is sent as versions:["1.0.1":{"vnum": "1.0.1", "vloc": "http://..."}, "1.0.2":{...}]

log("Populating:")
cbVSel.Items.Clear()

MessageBox.Show(vNum.Length) 'Returns 1
For Each ver As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In vNum
    Dim k As String = ver.Keys(0)
    MessageBox.Show(k.ToString()) 'Returns 1.0.2
Next
```

I feel like its simple but I have been working on this for a while now. I have also tried different Objects like HashTable, Array, Dictionary.

So In short. How can I get this working; Populating vNum with all the versions from JSON Array

If You need to see the JSON Parsing code let me know. Any Help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out. It was as simple as me using JSON wrong I changed the serverside to output:

```
{"payload":{"versions":[{"vnum":"1.0.2","vloc":"http:\/\/*domainomitted*\/flyswatter\/files\/flyswatter_102.zip"},{"vnum":"1.0.1","vloc":"http:\/\/*domainomitted*\/flyswatter\/files\/flyswatter_101.zip"}]}}
```

And all was well again. Thanks for your time!